# ODBC connection in VBA on a mac (excel 2011) to a postgresql db

Tags: database, macos, vba, odbc

I have a vba script in excel on a windows box that connects using ADO to a postgresql db.  I have to do the same on a mac.  From reading the posts on SO, I've:
- downloaded an odbc driver (openlink) on to the mac
- set up a DSN and successfully connected to the db

now to the vba change.  I've searched on SO, postgresql.org site, openlinks and some other places for a clear example, but haven't found it yet.  Here is the relevant vba code on the windows:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSomeValue As String

cnn.Open "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};DATABASE=<db>;SERVER=<target>;PORT=<port>;UID=<myusername>;PWD=<mypwd>"
```